# "se comporter en adulte" vs "se comporter comme un adulte"

Tags: sens, prépositions, comparatifs, compléments

In conversation, I just said:

> Tu as beau ne pas aimer leur attitude envers vous autres internes, il y a déjà longtemps que tu aurais dû apprendre à réfréner ta colère pour éviter les ennuis. Il faut savoir se comporter **en adulte**.

I'm wondering how "se comporter **comme un adulte**" would have compared. The same goes for "se comporter en homme d'affaires" vs "se comporter comme un homme d'affaires", for instance, and the list goes on.

Comment: My intuition is that *en* suggests a way of acting or being that's proper or natural to you, whereas *comme un(e)* has an element of pretense or at least having to attain to something. Say your 10-year-old throws a temper tantrum and you respond with frustration. You might say "Come on, you're ten years old!" or you might say "Come on, act like a ten-year-old!" They mean the same thing but the latter seems to distance them from their age, and could also be used of non-ten-year-olds. I'm not quite sure this is the nuance, though, so I'll wait to see what a native speaker says.

Answer (score 8):

Both forms are very close but there is a very slight difference:

> Il faut savoir se comporter en adulte

somewhat implies that the person is an adult (or close enough) and has to behave as such

> Il faut savoir se comporter comme un adulte

can be addressed to someone who is not yet an adult.

In the second example, *se comporter comme un homme d'affaire* suggests the person might not be a businessman, but rather someone who fakes being one (or aspires to be one).

With *se comporter en gentleman*, the behavior tend to be genuine, innate while with *se comporter comme un gentleman*, the behavior tend to be artificial, acquired.

Comment: Nice. Whenever you can say "se comporter comme un/une X", can you also use the form "se comporter en X" with the mentioned nuance?

Comment: e.g.: "se comporter comme un vrai gentleman" vs "se comporter en vrai gentleman"

Comment: I would say it is less likely to happen but not impossible, as your last example shows.

Comment: Pour en arriver à cette différence de sens, tu extrapoles à partir d'une analyse de la préposition _en_  par opposition à la comparaison ou c'est par ton expérience de la langue ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je n'ai pas fait de recherches ou d'analyse, c'est juste comme ça que je ressent la différence qui est quand même ténue, les deux expressions se recouvrant.

Comment: J'ai fait une recherche là-dessus mais de même je n'aurais pu percevoir ça. Le TLFi à _en_ pour la matière contient un truc intéressant du genre une table faite avec du bois est une table en bois, et traite d'intériorisation dans ce contexte. Pour moi la différence est syntaxique, _comme_ n'est pas une préposition et donc il y a une proposition en dessous de ça, même à vrai dire le complément _comme un adulte_ ne ressemble pas au complément essentiel du verbe _se comporter_. La prép. sollicite davantage l'essence du verbe que la comparative, mais c'est au final un propos assez ennuyeux...

Comment: Je supporte jlliagre dans son interprétation, mais en tentant de l'expliquer je confirme également que la différence est vraiment ténue, de l'ordre de la subtile nuance, tellement subtile qu'elle sera selon moi comprise exactement de la même manière si les 2 formules ne sont pas directement opposées.

Answer (score 1):

Although that's no indication, "se comporter en adulte" is much more used than "se comporter comme un adulte" [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comporter+comme+un+adulte%2Ccomporter+en+adulte&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomporter%20comme%20un%20adulte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomporter%20en%20adulte%3B%2Cc0).

In the TLFi can be found the following lexicographer's definition;

> [En parlant d'un enfant, d'un adolescent qui prétend agir, se comporter en adulte]

In the light of this usage, one can't claim that « se comporter comme un adulte » should be intended ony for those persons that are no adults and « se comporter en adulte » for a variety of context including the former. If there is a distinction it must be on an other level.

I'll submit the following personal insight into the question, without supporting contentions as I can't find any, and with the simple advice to the reader to remain critical.
The behaviour understated in the use of "en" implies a set of attitudes,  that either are not usual for the person considered or that are recognised as typical of what is expected of an adult in a given circumstance; in other words, in this latter case, the form with "en" would be used when it is question of a norm.

- (**a**) Il n'a que treize ans mais il se comporte **en** adulte en de nombreuses occasions.
- (**b**) (*Also*) Il n'a que treize ans mais il se comporte **comme** un adulte en de nombreuses circonstances.
- (**c**) Il s'est fait insulter d'une manière ignoble devant les employés mais il s'est comporté **en** adulte et a rappelé au diffamateur qu'il aurait à répondre de ses excès au tribunal.

However, we have this;

- (**d**) Il s'est fait insulter d'une manière ignoble devant les employés et il s'est comporté **comme** un idiot et a envoyé un coup de poing dans la figure du diffamateur ; il va passer au tribunal pour ça.

Note that in this last example (**d**) "en" can't be used; this is generally true, the derogatory term takes "comme";

- (**e**) Si vous agissez **comme** un voleur vous serez traité comme un voleur.
- (**f**) À agir **comme** un fou vous n'y gagnerez rien !
- (**g**) Il l'avait conseillée **en** homme de foi, sans lui laisser de faux espoirs.
- (**i**) Pris au piège dans cette sale histoire il avait choisi d'agir quand même **en** homme d'affaire.

In the example « **b** », the preposition "comme" seems to be  not as relevant for the reason that the behaviour described is not so much considered from the point of view of behaviour that is not usual or merely embraced, but behaviour in strict adhesion to the norms.

Beyond the aforementioned rather imperceptible differences, I tend to find no difference between the two forms.